# Can not install any package in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, package-managers

I can not install any package from NuGet package manager or package manager console. When i try it gives error.

Error description is;
"An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.4.1' from source .."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to reinstall it and fix your problem.

first Remove the package

```
Uninstall-Package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource -force
```

and Reinstall the package

```
Install-Package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource
```

For more information about how to reinstall and update nuget packages , please turn to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages